# Proving that the projection map from Cartesian product is onto

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

I am trying to prove the following theorem.

> Let $(X_i)_{i \in I}$ be a collection of nonempty sets. Using the Axiom of Choice, prove that for any $i_0 \in I$, the projection map
> $$
> \pi_{i_0}: \prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i \to X_{i_0}, \; (x_i)_{i \in I} \mapsto x_{i_0}. 
> $$

If $I = \emptyset$, the statement seems vacuously true, so I'm going to proceed under the assumption that $I$ is nonempty. I'm having some difficulty figuring out exactly where I can use choice.

> Fix $i_0 \in I$, and let $y \in X_{i_0}$. As $\prod\limits_{i \in I} X_i$ consists of all tuples $(x_i)_{i \in I}$ where $x_i \in X_i$ for each $i \in I$, there exists some tuple consisting of $y \in X_{i_0}$. The image of this tuple under $\pi_{i_0}$ is then $y$, so $\pi_{i_0}$ is surjective.

I feel as though this cannot be right. The problem makes clear I should be using the axiom of choice somewhere, which tells me that the product set is nonempty. Even if it is nonempty, however, that doesn't guarantee a tuple whose $i_{0}th$ position is $y$.

I'd appreciate some clarification on this. I'll update this post as I continue to work on this problem.

Answer (score 2):

The axiom of choice is used precisely where you say: "there exists some tuple ..."

Note it is not possible for you to manually define this tuple. You need to use the axiom of choice to conclude the existence of some function: $$g:I\setminus\{i_0\}\to\bigcup_{i\in I\setminus\{i_0\}}X_i$$With the property $g(i)\in X_i$ for every $i$. If we expect $g$ to always exist in general, then this is equivalent to the axiom of choice iirc.

Then we have a tuple: $$y_j:=\begin{cases}g(j)&j\neq i_0\\y&j=i_0\end{cases}$$How else do you actually *prove* the existence of a tuple $y_\bullet$ featuring $y$?

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful. My only question is: is the idea that after we have a function $g$, we then define $g(i_0) = y$? In this way, we haven't manually defined the tuple, but tweaked the tuple that the axiom of choice guaranteed the existence of?

Comment: @BradG. The idea is just that we don't know how to, in general, explicit define $y_j$ if $j\neq i_0$. So we appeal to the axiom of choice to just, make it happen. I guess you could say this is "tweaking" $g$. Technically speaking we can't define $g(i_0)=y$, this would be a new function (call it $g'$, maybe)